# Configuration postgresql in Djnago

Tags: django

I'm completely new to Django so sorry if I forgot to add something.

I'm trying to change my SQLite db to Postgres. I changed `settings.py` to include postgres instead of sqlite, but `python manage.py migrate` is still doing sqlite db (and show me `OperationalError at / no such table: articles_article`.
Here's how my db settings look like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'grokoko_db',
        'USER': 'grokoko',
        'PASSWORD': 'GROKOKO_DB_PASS',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

And here is full error:

```
OperationalError at /
no such table: articles_article
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: articles_article
Exception Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 298
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['F:\\Github\\Django\\Djangoject',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 12 Apr 2019 13:10:49 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template F:\Github\Django\Djangoject\djangoject\templates\base_layout.html, error at line 0

no such table: articles_article
1   {% load static from staticfiles %}
2   
3   <!DOCTYPE html>
4   <html>
5   <head>
6       <meta charset="utf-8">
7       <title>Articles</title>
8       <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'styles.css' %}">
9   </head>
10  <body>
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) ...
▶ Local vars
The above exception (no such table: articles_article) was the direct cause of the following exception:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
F:\Github\Django\Djangoject\articles\views.py in article_list
    return render(request, 'articles/article_list.html', {'articles': articles}) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py in render
            return self.template.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                    return self._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render
            len_values = len(values) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in __len__
        self._fetch_all() ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in _fetch_all
            self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self)) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py in execute_sql
            cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in execute
            return super().execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py in __exit__
                raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) ...
▶ Local vars
Request information
USER
AnonymousUser

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   
'5XCUdvt8KVmEXFmXlJVBl3XqrVu8kmXwTO1gxS7hsSVQFLDrJiFjZKgjbEaR89x1'
META
Variable    Value
ALLUSERSPROFILE 
'C:\\ProgramData'
APPDATA 
'C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Roaming'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES  
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMW6432  
'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMPUTERNAME    
'DESKTOP-OPRI24M'
COMSPEC 
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'5XCUdvt8KVmEXFmXlJVBl3XqrVu8kmXwTO1gxS7hsSVQFLDrJiFjZKgjbEaR89x1'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'djangoject.settings'
DRIVERDATA  
'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData'
EXEPATH 
'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin'
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING  
'Internet Explorer'
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING 
'Default'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
GROKOKO_DB_PASS 
'Jesien2013!'
HOME    
'C:\\Users\\groko'
HOMEDRIVE   
'C:'
HOMEPATH    
'\\Users\\groko'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5'
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL  
'max-age=0'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'csrftoken=5XCUdvt8KVmEXFmXlJVBl3XqrVu8kmXwTO1gxS7hsSVQFLDrJiFjZKgjbEaR89x1'
HTTP_HOST   
'localhost:8000'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
 'Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36')
LANG    
'pl_PL.UTF-8'
LOCALAPPDATA    
'C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Local'
LOGONSERVER 
'\\\\DESKTOP-OPRI24M'
MSYSTEM 
'MINGW64'
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    
'4'
OLDPWD  
'F:/Github/Django'
ONEDRIVE    
'C:\\Users\\groko\\OneDrive'
ONEDRIVECONSUMER    
'C:\\Users\\groko\\OneDrive'
OS  
'Windows_NT'
PATH    
('C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\groko\\bin;C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\;C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\Python37-32\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files (x86)\\NVIDIA '
 'Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program '
 'Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client '
 'SDK\\ODBC\\110\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL '
 'Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL '
 'Server\\120\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL '
 'Server\\120\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\;C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32;C:\\Program '
 'Files (x86)\\Python37-32;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\PostgreSQL\\11\\bin;C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\bin;C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft '
 'VS Code\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\heroku\\bin')
PATHEXT 
'.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW'
PATH_INFO   
'/'
PLINK_PROTOCOL  
'ssh'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  
'x86'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432  
'AMD64'
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel'
PROCESSOR_LEVEL 
'6'
PROCESSOR_REVISION  
'2a07'
PROGRAMDATA 
'C:\\ProgramData'
PROGRAMFILES    
'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMFILES(X86)   
'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMW6432    
'C:\\Program Files'
PS1 
('\\[\\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\\007\\]\\n\\[\\033[32m\\]\\u@\\h '
 '\\[\\033[35m\\]$MSYSTEM '
 '\\[\\033[33m\\]\\w\\[\\033[36m\\]`__git_ps1`\\[\\033[0m\\]\\n$ ')
PSMODULEPATH    
('C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules;C:\\Program '
 'Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules\\')
PUBLIC  
'C:\\Users\\Public'
PWD 
'F:/Github/Django/Djangoject'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SECRET_KEY  
'rp^529&1%^s-8t*9jty*^t#$y164j3$x*q2j%dm!1f5m1(xr-6'
SERVER_NAME 
'DESKTOP-OPRI24M'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSIONNAME 
'Console'
SHLVL   
'1'
SYSTEMDRIVE 
'C:'
SYSTEMROOT  
'C:\\WINDOWS'
TEMP    
'C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
TERM    
'cygwin'
TERM_PROGRAM    
'vscode'
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION    
'1.33.1'
TMP 
'C:\\Users\\groko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
USERDOMAIN  
'DESKTOP-OPRI24M'
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE   
'DESKTOP-OPRI24M'
USERNAME    
'groko'
USERPROFILE 
'C:\\Users\\groko'
WINDIR  
'C:\\WINDOWS'
_   
'C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python'
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
wsgi.input  
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.LimitedStream object at 0x04C3CAB0>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module djangoject.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
['0.0.0.0', 'localhost', 'fierce-brook-69212.herokuapp.com']
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
'F:\\Github\\Django\\Djangoject'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': 'F:\\Github\\Django\\Djangoject\\db.sqlite3',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
FORM_RENDERER   
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'articles',
 'accounts']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
'F:\\Github\\Django\\Djangoject\\media'
MEDIA_URL   
'/media/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'djangoject.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'djangoject.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
('F:\\Github\\Django\\Djangoject\\assets',)
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
'F:\\Github\\Django\\Djangoject\\staticfiles'
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['djangoject/templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'djangoject.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
```

`datadump > json` didn't work because of same problem. Secret key and db pass added as environement variable with setx command. I don't really get why, but I have two settings.py files, but when I'm trying to change that deeper one everything is going wild and I can't even runserver as I'm getting `NameError: name 'get_env_variable' is not defined`. When I'm changing only db settings it's still no good:

```
python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0495CA98>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

Little background: I made app with Django youtube tutorial by Netninja. It didn't have anything about deploying app online, hiding secret things or changing db so it's possible that I did more mistakes while searching for that. Site is currently online at https://fierce-brook-69212.herokuapp.com/ (without working db) and here is it's code https://github.com/grokoko/Django

Edit.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: Edited according to advice. If there's anything more I can do better, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First Delete all migrations files,
then try:

> python manage.py migrate --fake

the do anather time makemigrate and migrate

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',                      
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'db_user_password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': 'db_port_number',
    }
}
```

Comment: All three commands results in no changes detected/no migrations to apply. But then when I try to runserver and check things locally I'm still getting ```OperationalError at /
no such table: articles_article```

Comment: is there any queryset in views.py you use `articles_article` model ?? because before migrating something django checks views.py if there  articles_article` queryset commit it and then check

Comment: I've tried to check and found nothing like that, but it's possible that I'm just not getting what you mean by 'queryset'. (or why it would a problem if nothing has changed there). Would love if you could explain it further or check by yourself here: https://github.com/grokoko/Django/blob/master/djangoject/articles/views.py

Answer (score 0):

> When connecting to other database backends, such as MySQL, Oracle, or PostgreSQL, additional connection parameters will be required. See the ENGINE setting below on how to specify other database types. This example is for PostgreSQL:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

Then migrate using

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

See [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases)

To migrate from sqlite to postgres see [this Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/sirodoht/f598d14e9644e2d3909629a41e3522ad)

Comment: As I said in question this method is not working, because dumpdata is giving me an error: ```CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such table: articles_article ```

Comment: `No changes detected`